# AngularJS $scope no longer available in chrome console

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, scope, console

If you see this example:

https://www.ng-book.com/p/Debugging-AngularJS/

We can simply view our scope typing in console (using jquery):

```
$("[ng-controller]").scope()
```

My old app, works perfectly. I Always used this method for debug quickly the apps, but I created a new app and this is no longer showing scope in console.

throw the error: `$(...).scope is not a function`

Why?? They removed anything?

Comment: Do you have `$compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);` anywhere in your app?

Comment: Yes, is in true

Answer (score 2):

According to this [link](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production), if you have the following code in your app:

```
myApp.config(['$compileProvider', function ($compileProvider) {
  $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(false);
}]);
```

then you should be able to get debug info again by running the following in your browser console:

```
angular.reloadWithDebugInfo();
```

Answer (score 1):

Auto-answer:

Seems like modern browsers $ selector, return differenet object now.
Using angular element selector, works:
[See this example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FtJk.jpg)